# == operator not working on two matching strings

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I have been debugging this code and couldn't make the `==` operator work on two matching strings.

The code:

```
str1 = "string1"
str2 = "string2"

print str1
print str2

for row in results:
  print row[0]
  print row[1]   #as requested
  if((row[0] == str1) and (row[1] == str2)):
     print "We found the match....."
     #rest of the code
```

Comment: Do they both match at the same time? Some sample data would be great.

Comment: That's not syntactically correct, you've got an extra bracket. Post your actual code...

Comment: Also print some sample values of `row[0]` and `row[2]`. Unicode issue perhaps?

Comment: Print the repr() of the strings.  Likely you have newlines at the end of the rows, but easy to debug if you print them.

Comment: I have print the values, they are same as the strings above in the code, @nneonnneo I tried out matching only the first strings so that why it missed the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Have you checked the types of row[0] and row[1]?  Also, note that your indexes (0, 2) are different than the numbering on the str variables (1, 2).

Comment: 1. You failed to put the `print row` lines where they would actually occur. 2. You failed to show the output of the prints in your question - how can anyone help you debug if you don't show the data? There's nothing wrong with your syntax, so it must be the data.

Comment: @mtrw thanks for the demerits, I am honored. Thanks again for your input too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you clean out the whitespace with `.strip()`.

```
>>> str1 = "string1"
>>> str2 = "string2"
>>>
>>> results = [["string1 ", " string2"]]
>>> for row in results:
...   if((row[0].strip() == str1) and (row[1].strip() == str2)):
...      print "We found the match....."
...
We found the match.....
>>>
```